# Some baseball game theory. You lose one game so that your odds of winning more games increases. Is there a math concept which represents this idea?

Tags: game-theory

I never really liked baseball as I always thought it was too slow, but in an effort to make playoff pushes and being that baseball is a numbers game, I had this idea. Usually teams have their best pitchers face off. My thought was, why not put your worst pitcher against their best pitcher and alter your rotation accordingly downward. Your odds for winning more games would increase, if you simply concede that one game.
Is there a math concept which represents this idea?

Comment: This kind of thing is at the heart of **game theory**. (Although most commonly, game theory deals in absolute results, not probabilities of results one way or the other, given each player's choice. I'm sure there is an established way of dealing with that, though.)

Comment: At the extreme, it's clear that there is something to this.  If, say, the opposing team has a pitcher who never loses, then it obviously makes sense to save your talent for later games.  But it all depends on the specific probabilities.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, this particular problem is well known and even has a name: Colonel Blotto's problem, how to divide up your resources when facing an opponent.
https://www.rdmag.com/news/2016/02/after-nearly-century-colonel-blotto-game-theory-scenario-solved
How many men do you send to which battlefield? The baseball problem  might  be a bit lumpier, but it has the same idea.